# How do i make so that my bot changes status every 10 seconds?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

This is my code, someone said that I should use `Math.floor` but I don't know where exactly should I place it

```
bot.user.setActivity({ name: 'Arth agora em JavaScript~', type: 'PLAYING' })
});
```

Comment: Your snippet syntax is not valid. To set up a recurring thing you should probably use setInterval: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: Changing status every ten seconds would break Discord TOS

Comment: Adding on to @Octogonal T, Having your bot do Any X every Y seconds is considered API Spam

Answer (score 0):

You will need an array of different activities, you can insert as many as you like.

`setInterval` executes the code inside the arrow function every ten seconds (specified by 10000 milliseconds). The code inside the arrow function will randomly choose an activity from the array.

```
const activities = [
    { name: 'Arth agora em JavaScript~', type: 'PLAYING' },
    { name: 'Another activity', type: 'PLAYING' }
];

setInterval(() => bot.user.setActivity(activities[Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length)]), 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive setTimeout (better than setInterval) that will execute every amount of time you want and won't cause any type of memory leak.

```
function Foo(){
    // your code here

   setTimeout(Foo, 5000); // you can define your function and the amount of time here

}

Foo();
```

I'm not so sure about your request, but you want your bot's status changes every x seconds, you can apply your concept in your code and use **Math.random()** to generate a random number with this type of function:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

**Math.floor()** only rounds a number to its nearest integer.

So finally, you can combine both code and obtain this:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}


function updateStatus(){
    bot.user.setActivity({ name: 'Random Status : ' + getRandomInt(1, 200), type: 'PLAYING' })
    });

   setTimeout(updateStatus, 5000); // you can define your function and the amount of time here

}

updateStatus();
```

However, i will advice you to build a more complicated structure like client-server to refresh packets on every amount of time but i don't even know your entire code.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the bot activity/status

```
const activities_list = [
    "RANDOM", 
    "help",
    "Random Status"
]; 

setInterval(() => bot.user.setActivity(activities[Math.floor(Math.random() * activities_list.length)]), 10000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `setInterval()`:

```
setInterval(function () {
    bot.user.setActivity({ name: 'Arth agora em JavaScript~', type: 'PLAYING' });
}, 10000); // 10 000 miliseconds = 10 seconds
```